# Google Groups: Outbox?

Tags: google-groups

I wrote a mail to a group and it is the first time that I post to this group.

The post does not show. That's ok, since the first posts get moderated.

But I would like to see the text I wrote.

Is there some kind of "outbox" where I can see the posts I wrote?

Answer (score 4):

Google Groups doesn't have an "outbox" but there is a "Manage messages".  For further details go to the related help article: [Moderate pending posts - Google Groups Help](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2466386?hl=en)

If you are not a moderator and you are allowed to post by email, send an email instead of posting directly from the web page of the group.

If you want that an "outbox" be added to Google Groups, you should consider to send feedback to Google requesting this feature. To do so,

1. Go to http://groups.google.com
2. Optional go to your group.
3. Click on the gear button then on Help and Feedback
4. Click on "Send Feedback", fill the form an submit it.

Comment: I am the author, not the moderator. Maybe I am missing something, but I could not find a way to see my post if the information provided with above link.

Comment: @guettli: I updated my answer.

Comment: This does not satisfy me: "send an email instead of posting directly from the web page of the group". Sorry if this offends you. It should not, except you work for google and you are responsible for this product.

Comment: No problem at all. By the way I don't work for Google.

Comment: Added instructions regarding how to send feedback (feature requests) to the Google Groups team.

Comment: I gave feedback via the way you described.